# Product homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

Let $(G,+)$ and $(H,\star)$ be groups (with respectively noted relations $+$ and $\star$). Let $f$ and $g$ be group homomorphisms $f,g:G \to H$.

Claim: If $H$ is abelian, then the product map $f \cdot g,\,x \mapsto f(x) \star g(x)$ is also a homomorphism.

I was able to prove this, but now I am wondering if there exists a concrete but simple counterexample for when $H$ is not abelian... (e.g. with whole numbers under addition or similar...)

Comment: The smallest non-abelian group is $S_3$. Try it.

Comment: I meant to write $f \cdot g,\, x \mapsto f(x) \star g(x)$ (I think...) . @Dietrich Burde: Yes I thought of symmetric groups as well, for I know that $S_3$ is not abelian. But it would be nice to find something more „basic“ with numbers, as I find those to be more comprehensible and intuitive.

Comment: @PhilippeKnecht you are free to edit your post.

Comment: If you want 'numbers', you should go as far as the quaternions to get a noncommutative group operation. So, check out the 8 element quaternion group, maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could consider the left multiplications $\ell_\pi:S_n\rightarrow S_n:\sigma\mapsto\pi\sigma$ with given $\pi\in S_n$, where $S_n$ is the symmetric group on $n$ places.

The set of left multiplications $L(S_n)$ forms a group under function composition, since
$\ell_\pi\ell_\sigma=\ell_{\pi\sigma}$, $(\ell_\pi)^{-1} = \ell_{\pi^{-1}}$ and $\ell_e= id$ is the identity mapping, where $e$ is the identity permutation.

Consider the mapping $F:S_n \rightarrow L(S_n):\pi\mapsto \ell_\pi$, which is a homomorphism, since $F(\pi\sigma) =\ell_{\pi\sigma} = \ell_\pi\ell_\sigma = F(\pi)F(\sigma)$.